# How can I toggleClass on this element and hide others?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to toggle show a megamenu clicking on his parent tag and at the same time close all other megamenu if opened.

with my basic example code (just to explain the problem) I can open the current megamenu, close the others but clicking another time on the current it remains opened...

any solutions? jquery or vanilla is not a problem. Thanks!

this is my markup (with tailwindcss):

```js
let hasMegamenu = $('.has-megamenu');

hasMegamenu.on('click', function() {
  $('.megamenu').addClass('hidden');
  var thisMM = $(this).find('.megamenu');
  if (thisMM.hasClass('hidden')) {
    console.log('has hidden');
    thisMM.removeClass('hidden');
  } else {
    console.log('has not hidden');
    thisMM.addClass('hidden');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<nav>
  <ul>
    <li class="has-megamenu">Link1
      <div class="megamenu hidden">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sublink1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sublink2</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="has-megamenu">Link2
      <div class="megamenu hidden">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sublink1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sublink2</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: This has been asked and answered hundreds of times. Have you searched?

Comment: hi, yes but not my case, everything it's ok but not the last part, when I want to close the open megamenu :(

Comment: You might think through your logic. Your first `if` condition will _always_ be true because of the line right above it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest a different approach:

- make Megamenus CSS  hidden by default `.has-megamenu .megamenu{display:none;}`
- use a `.is-open` instead - directly on the `.has-megamenu` element
- Use [.not()](https://api.jquery.com/not/) to filter out the clicked one and remove the class `.is-open`
- Use [.toggleClass()](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) to toggle the clicked one's class `.is-open`
- There's still yet something to fix:
  If you want to be able to click on your Megamenu child but not abruptly close the parent you need to detect who initiated the click, the button or the megamenu:

```js
const $hasMegamenu = $(".has-megamenu");

$hasMegamenu.on("click", function(evt) {
  if ($(evt.target).closest(".megamenu").length) return; // Allow clicks inside the megamenu

  $hasMegamenu.not(this).removeClass("is-open"); // Close all (but this)
  $(this).toggleClass("is-open"); // Toggle this
});

// Close if clicked outside
$(document).on("click", (evt) => {
  if (!$(evt.target).closest(".has-megamenu").length) {
    $hasMegamenu.removeClass("is-open");
  }
});
```

```css
.has-megamenu .megamenu { display: none; }
.has-megamenu.is-open .megamenu { display: block; }
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li class="has-megamenu">Link1
      <div class="megamenu">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sublink1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sublink2</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="has-megamenu">Link2
      <div class="megamenu">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sublink1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sublink2</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

### Pure JavaScript variant:

```js
// DOM utility functions:

const el = (sel, par) => (par || document).querySelector(sel);
const els = (sel, par) => (par || document).querySelectorAll(sel);


// Task: Megamenu:

const elsHM = els(".has-megamenu");

elsHM.forEach(elHM => {
  elHM.addEventListener("click", (evt) => {
    if (evt.target.closest(".megamenu")) return; // Allow clicks inside the megamenu
    elsHM.forEach(elHM => {
      if (evt.currentTarget === elHM) elHM.classList.toggle("is-open");
      else elHM.classList.remove("is-open");
    });
  });
});


// Close if clicked outside
document.documentElement.addEventListener("click", (evt) => {
  if (evt.target.closest(".has-megamenu")) return;
  elsHM.forEach(elHM => elHM.classList.remove("is-open"));
});
```

```css
.has-megamenu .megamenu { display: none; }
.has-megamenu.is-open .megamenu { display: block; }
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li class="has-megamenu">Link1
      <div class="megamenu">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sublink1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sublink2</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="has-megamenu">Link2
      <div class="megamenu">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sublink1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sublink2</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: @LorenzoFranzone added also a fix to allow clicks inside the actual megamenu (prevent close the megamenu if a megamenu received he event)

Comment: hi @roko, i'm back :) your code works and I have no problems :) but if I would like to close the megamenu or all clicking outside? there is a little trick? thank you

Comment: @LorenzoFranzone sure, added to my answer

Comment: hello @Roko C. Buljan I don't wanna be your nightmare eheh :) I've the latest question about your solution, always for learning purpose, I need to convert your jQuery code to vanilla javascript, if you have time could you help me... I've some problems converting some jQuery functions so after some tears I invoke the Roko card :). Thanks a lot

Comment: @LorenzoFranzone added an example in pure JS

Comment: Super! @Roko C. Buljan